# How to match any repeated chunks of characters?

Tags: c#, regex

I've seen many questions similar to this but none quite like it.

I have strings like this:

```
HF-01-HF-01-01
FBC-FBC-04
OZYA-03A-OZYA-03A-03
QC-QC-02
```

and want them to be returned like so:

```
HF-01-01
FBC-04
OZYA-03A-03
QC-02
```

I can't figure this out and the other questions I've seen don't apply because 1) the repeated chunk is more than one character, 2) There are no spaces between the repetition.

Or is regex not the best way to do this?

EDIT:
**Rules**

- Alpha chunks are never repeated more than one time.
- Some chunks can be alphanumeric but also never repeated more than one
  time.
- The part that can be repeated would be from the start of the string
  and any  additional chunks by hyphen.

So you would never have something like HF-HF-01-01. But in this case using the above rules, it would become HF-01-01 since HF is the only part repeated from the beginning of the string.

Perhaps something like this would work:
Scan string to first hyphen, see if that matches anywhere else after first hyphen, if so scan to second hyphen, see if that matches anywhere else, if not, take the first scan and remove one instance of it from the string, if so, scan to third, etc.

But I don't know how to do that in regex.

Comment: The obvious question is what _`chunks`_ can be repeated ?

Comment: On `FBC-FBC-04` there is no repeat of the `04` chunk. What special rule matches `FBC-04` ?

Comment: Unclear to me too. What about eg `QC-QC-QC-02` -> `QC-02` ? Or `QC-QC-QC-QC-02` -> `QC-QC-02` ? Thought of something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/X1ECaj/1).

Comment: It's a good question, but not clear; what exactly are the rules? Is it that each pair of duplicate chunks are reduced to one single chunk (see @bobblebubble's examples)

Comment: The above scenario by @bobblebubble wouldn't apply. I updated the question. Alpha chunks are never repeated more than once.

Answer (score 2):

I guess,

```
([^-\r\n]+-|[^-\r\n]+-[^-\r\n]+-)(\1.*)
```

or with start/end anchors,

```
^([^-\r\n]+-|[^-\r\n]+-[^-\r\n]+-)(\1.*)$
```

might work to some extent and the desired output is in the last capturing group:

```
(\1.*)
```

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/bwmDuD/1/)

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/xD2Q73/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"([^-\r\n]+-|[^-\r\n]+-[^-\r\n]+-)(\1.*)";
        string input = @"HF-01-HF-01-01
FBC-FBC-04
OZYA-03A-OZYA-03A-03
QC-QC-02

and want them to be returned like so:

HF-01-01
FBC-04
OZYA-03A-03
QC-02";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/bwmDuD/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/bwmDuD/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if regex is the right tool here, but atleast it can be somewhat done with this short pattern:

```
^([A-Z0-9]+)-.*(\1.*)$
```

Explanation:

- `^` start of string
- `(` group 1 start
- `[A-Z0-9]+` one or more capital letters or digits
- `)` end group 1
- `-` literal
- `.*` any number of any chars
- `(` group 2 start
- `\1` anything that was matched in group 1
- `.*` any number of any chars
- `)` end group 2 (this group will be used as the result)
- `$` end of string

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if RegExp is the right tool here.

Using [MoreLinq](https://morelinq.github.io/) [RunLengthEncode](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/README.md#runlengthencode) method (that implement [R.L.E.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)) you can achieve it like this:

```
string RemoveDuplicate(string input)
{
  var chunks = input.Split('-')             // cut at -
                    .RunLengthEncode()      // group and count adjacent equals chunck
                    .Select(kvp => kvp.Key);// just take the chunk value
  return string.Join("-", chunks);          // reglue with -
}
```

*Edit*

Doesn't work for:

```
OZYA-03A-OZYA-03A-03
```